# Audioquest Dragonfly distorted sound

Tags: sound

I own audioquest dragonfly, the red and the newly launched dragonfly cobalt.Both worked fine with windows but in my new setup with ubuntu 18.04 the sound is distorted and as it appears not functioning at all.Audioquest on their website mention that audioquest cobalt is linux capable(but not suppoted).Is their a way that can fix this.I have another dac which works fine with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please verify the registered USB audio class etc. with the package [alsa-capabilities](https://github.com/ronalde/mpd-configure/blob/master/alsa-capabilities) with `alsa-capabilities -l u` and maybe see its setting the output format in pavucontrol. I have a cobalt which works perfectly on Manjaro.